# Run mvn command on module from existing source

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I imported several maven modules on `IntelliJ IDEA` by using the option `File/New/Module From Existing Source`. This is working fine but I'm not able to run `mvn` command lines on one specific module by its module name.

I was able to do it by specifying the path to the `pom.xml` file by using `-f` option:

```
mvn -f "path/to/pom.xml" clean
```

But I would like to avoid having specifying the path every time I want to run a mvn command. Is their any way to run the command by specifiying the name of the module ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you use "Run Anything" then it's possible to select module at the top right corner.

Comment: That's right. Did not knew this trick. If you post your comment as an answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "Run Anything" then it's possible to select module at the top right corner

Answer (score 0):

You can perform maven install, maven clean etc for a complete module or sub modules of a project using top right option in IntelliJ.

**Maven-->select module/submodule folder-->Plugins-->select the option**:- deploy, compile, install, clean etc.